# Keep Values in a dynamically created dropdown list after selection

Tags: php, html

I'm working on an old, out of date webpage which displays data from a database. My task is to enable the selection of some values in order to narrow down what the user is looking at.

I have created a dynamic dropdown list based upon what a certain field within the database is set to. The problem I am having is that once the dropdown selection is made the dropdown resets to default.

I've looked through methods to allow to option to be retained once selected and the page refreshes. However these all require php statements which doesn't work with the method I have used.

Please see the code below. Please ignore $past as this is a variable set for a certain amount of time in the past.

```
<?php
//Section to fill the Department dropdown
$dropdown = "SELECT `ResponsibleGroup` FROM 'table` WHERE `Change_Start_Time` > '$past' AND `Change_Start_Time` < '$future' AND `Status` NOT LIKE 'Cancelled' AND `Status` NOT LIKE 'New' AND `Status` NOT LIKE 'Re-Scheduling' GROUP BY `ResponsibleGroup` ORDER BY `ResponsibleGroup` ASC";

$dropres = mysqli_query($con,$dropdown);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dropres))
{
    echo"<option value='" .$row['ResponsibleGroup'] ."'>" . $row['ResponsibleGroup'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</form>
```

The suggestions I've seen suggest putting an if isset PHP statement in the  field however, i've not been able to get this to work. I've tried doing exactly as they suggested and just using <?php .... within the echo, which doesn't work. Like the below:

```
<select name="operator">
    <option value="add" <?php echo (isset($_POST['operator']) && $_POST['operator'] == 'add') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>+</option>
```

I've also tried similar to the above while breaking out of the echo but i can't get that to work either.

Any help or advice on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you execute the same PHP code to build the dropdown selector, when the page refreshed, the same selector should appear. It is unclear why this doesn't happen, but the logical thing to conclude is that you do not execute the same PHP code.

Comment: It's the same code that gets executed but executing the code will refresh the list from the DB which could have changed since the last refresh. The reason i needed the dropdown to be dynamic that that field can be set to be 129 different values, most of which won't be relevant all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById('department').value="<?php echo $_POST['department'];?>"; </script>
```

Comment: Could you clarify how your answer solves the question being asked?